# Accessing Bluetooth stack on a remote desktop server

Tags: bluetooth, client, server, remote-desktop

I have to get access to Bluetooth on a remote machine.

Here's how things are connected.

External Bluetooth Adapter connected to the client running the Remote desktop application.
The Remote Desktop should identify the device connected to the client since its connected to the USB port, but I am not able to access the Bluetooth stack on the remote desktop.

I just need to get the list of Bluetooth devices which is present near the client to appear on the server. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KC-4132 is an embedded Class 1 Bluetooth USB Serial Adapter. This adapter enumerates using FTDI USB-UART bridge chip, so you get a virtual COM port. After sending the kcSerial command "AT Discovery" via COM port to the adapter, it will respond with a listing of all Bluetooth devices currently in range and discoverable. No messy Bluetooth stacks or drivers to interface with since the Bluetooth device is an embedded serial port adapter with its own command language.